# How to calculate the area under the precision-recall curve for the random classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, roc, precision-recall

I know that the random classifier score in ROC AUC (Area under the curve) is always 0.5. My question is: how to calculate the Area under the precision-recall curve for the random classifier?

Comment: The PR curve is fragile, and not well-defined (at 0 recall, the precision is not defined). Maybe something like classic Average Precision is the better choice?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse how is precision not defined at 0 recall? if recall=0 then True Positive is zero. if you check the Precision formula, you have a False Positive in the denominator, so it can't be undefined.

Comment: If the first element is positive, what is the accuracy at recall=0?  As long as it is a miss, you are okay, but if it is correct, then your curve doesn't start at recall=0. If you retrieve 0 elements, then the denominator is 0, and cannot simply be resolved by L'Hôpitals rule - it could be anything from 0 to 1.